# Problems creating table after normalisation

Tags: oracle, database-normalization, 3nf

I have been given a task to normalise a sales order, create a relational schema and input the data into SQL developer.

I have normalised to 3NF and got this:

```
Customer(Customer_ID, Customer_name)
Primary key Customer_ID

Employee(Employee_ID, Employee_name)
Primary key Employee_ID

Sales_Order(Sales_order_ID, Employee_ID, Customer_ID, Sale_date, Order_total)
Primary key Sales_order_ID
Foreign keys Employee_ID, Customer_ID 

Order_Line(Sales_order_ID, Product_ID, Quantity, Line_total)
Composite key Sales_order_ID
Foreign key Product_ID
```

```
Product(Product_ID, Product_name, Product_price, Product_colour)
Primary key Product_ID

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
    Employee_ID CHAR(3), 
    Employee_name CHAR(20),  
    CONSTRAINT pk_Employee PRIMARY KEY (Employee_name)
);

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(
    Customer_ID CHAR(5), 
    Customer_Name CHAR(20),  
    CONSTRAINT pk_Customer PRIMARY KEY (Customer_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE PRODUCT(
    Product_ID CHAR(5),
    Product_Name CHAR(30),
    Product_Colour CHAR(10),
    Product_Price CHAR(5),
    CONSTRAINT pk_Product PRIMARY KEY (Product_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE SALES_ORDER(
    Sales_order_ID CHAR(6),
    Employee_ID CHAR(3),
    Customer_ID CHAR(5),
    Sale_Date CHAR(10),
    Order_total CHAR(7),
    CONSTRAINT pk_Order PRIMARY KEY (Sales_order_ID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Order FOREIGN KEY (Employee_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (Employee_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER (Customer_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ORDER_LINE(
    Sales_order_ID CHAR(6),
    Product_ID CHAR(5),
    Quantity CHAR(3),
    Line_total CHAR(5),
    CONSTRAINT pk_Order_Line PRIMARY KEY (Sales_order_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Product_ID) REFERENCES PRODUCT (Product_ID)
);
```

I am able to create tables `Employee`, `Customer`, `Product`, `Sales_order` but not `Order_line`.

I am told that the table or view does not exist.

What does this mean?

Have I normalised incorrectly?

Have I designed the relational schema incorrectly?

Comment: Those `CHAR` columns should really use the standard `VARCHAR2`. `CHAR` is a weird ANSI-compatibility type providing blank-padding that nobody needs.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Please ask one question per post. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular formatted initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your code in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4858183b3a5446c0dcf686d59b2bd8d0), creation of table `SALE_ORDER` fails with the following message:

> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

This is because of this foreign key:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_Order FOREIGN KEY (Employee_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (Employee_ID),
```

The underlying problem is that you have defined `Employee_name` as the primary key of table `EMPLOYEE`.

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
    Employee_ID CHAR(3), 
    Employee_name CHAR(20),  
    CONSTRAINT pk_Employee PRIMARY KEY (Employee_ID)
);
```

This does not seem like a sensible option. In the real life, it is possible that two different employees would have the same name. Instead, you probably want to use `Employee_ID` as the primary key for `EMPLOYEE`.

Consider this definition for table `EMPLOYEE`:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
    Employee_ID CHAR(3), 
    Employee_name CHAR(20),  
    CONSTRAINT pk_Employee PRIMARY KEY (Employee_ID)
);
```

With this new set up, all tables are created successfully. You may now insert your data.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6a588a00aac094a20f8082acc43e4c0a)**

---

Side note: I forsee issues with table `ORDER_LINE`:

- primary key should be `Order_line_ID` instead of `Sales_order_ID`
- `Sales_order_ID` should have a foreign key constraint referencing `SALE_ORDER(Sales_order_ID)`.

Consider this new definition for `ORDER_LINE`:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDER_LINE(
    Order_line_ID CHAR(6),
    Sales_order_ID CHAR(6),
    Product_ID CHAR(5),
    Quantity CHAR(3),
    Line_total CHAR(5),
    CONSTRAINT pk_Order_Line PRIMARY KEY (Order_line_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Product_ID) REFERENCES PRODUCT (Product_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Sales_order_ID) REFERENCES SALES_ORDER(Sales_order_ID)
);
```